# manipulate a defaultidict like a pd dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe which i turn into a defaultdict  with the 'id' column as the key and then the rest of the columns as the values so i do something like this:

```
d = {'id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4],
     'label':['A','A','B','G','A','BB','C','C','A','BB','B','AA','AA']
    ,'amount':[2,-12,12,-12,5,-5,2,3,5,3,3,10,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd


dd = defaultdict(list)

# turn df into a dictionary groyped by the 'id'
for  index,row in df.iterrows():
        dd[row["id"]].append(
            { 
                
                "description": row["label"],
                'amount':row['amount'] })
dd

defaultdict(list,
           {1:[{'id':1, 'description': 'A', 'amount': 2},
              {'id': 1, 'description': 'A', 'amount':-12},
              {'id': 1, 'description': 'B', 'amount': 12},
              {'id': 1, 'description': 'G', 'amount':-12}],
             2:[{'id': 2, 'description': 'A', 'amount': 5},
              {  'id': 2, 'description': 'BB', 'amount':-5}],
             3:[{'id': 3, 'description': 'C', 'amount': 2},
                {'id': 3, 'description': 'C', 'amount': 3},
                {'id': 3, 'description': 'A', 'amount': 5}],
            4:[{'id': 4, 'description': 'BB', 'amount': 3},
              {'id': 4, 'description': 'B', 'amount': 3},
              {'id': 4, 'description': 'AA', 'amount': 10},
              {'id': 4, 'description': 'AA', 'amount':10}]})
```

What i want to do is manipulate the dictionary like a pandas dataframe. For instance i want to check for each user if they the 'description' and 'amount' is equal across the records.
For the specific example i want my desired dictionary to look like this:

```
defaultdict(list,{4: [{'id': 4, 'description': 'AA', 'amount': 10},
                      {'id': 4, 'description': 'AA', 'amount': 10}]})
```

Comment: Hmmm, so need pandas methods for `defaultdict` ? What is reason? Why not use pandas for pandas methods and in last stp convert ouput to `defaultdict` ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion faster ans simplier is use pandas methods for DataFrame or Series not in `defaultdict`. So for your ouput is possible use:

```
#all columns
df = df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
#if need specify columns
#df = df[df.duplicated(['id','label','amount'], keep=False)]
print(df)
    id label  amount
11   4    AA      10
12   4    AA      10
```

Last id need dictionary use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
d = df.groupby(df['id']).apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient='records')).to_dict()
print(d)
{4: [{'id': 4, 'label': 'AA', 'amount': 10}, {'id': 4, 'label': 'AA', 'amount': 10}]}
```

Comment: This doesn't help me a lot because i wanted to check how to do operations(like check for equality between the records of one user) inside a dictionary and not by using a pandas operation as you did with the duplicates. So i want to check for equality after i have the dictionary.

Comment: @hippocampus - So sorry, then no idea.